# How to evaluate this formula

Tags: logarithms, problem-solving

How can I evaluate $1/e^{\ln(x)}$? I really don't have experience on this and appreciate if you can explain it to me.

Thanks.

Comment: $e^{\ln x}=x$ by definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition you have that $\ln(x) = y$ if and ony if $e^y = x$. Hence you would have that 
$$
e^{\ln(x)} = x.
$$
So in your example:

$$
\frac{1}{e^{\ln(x)}} = \frac{1}{x}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Implement the formula: $a^{\log_a b}=b$, and $\ln x=\log_e x$ we have:

$\frac{1}{e^{\ln (x)}}=\frac{1}{e^{\log_e (x)}}=\frac{1}{x}$